# Google Play Console разработчика. Как разрешить бесплатно устанавливать купленное приложение на другие устройства покупателя?

Tags: google-play-console, разрешение

Как (где в Google Play Console) поставить галочку, чтобы разрешить бесплатно устанавливать один раз купленное приложение на другие устройства покупателя, т.е. на устройства имеющие одинаковый аккаунт (логин и пароль)?

Comment: Так а разве их нельзя бесплатно устанавливать на другое устройство с тем же аккаунтом? Я все свои купленные приложения на все устройства установил. Или надо именно не больше одного раза?

Comment: Мне пишут, что нельзя. Я давно читал, что будет добавлена настройка (галочка) в консоли разработчика, чтобы разрешить бесплатную установку, один раз купленного приложения, на другие устройства для одного аккаунта, но найти ее не могу!!!)))...

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/113410?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=ru

Comment: никак не разрешить, потому что уже разрешено. Приложение покупается не на устройство, а на аккаунт.

Comment: @Эникейщик С моими приложениями что-то не то... Их не видно в семейной библиотеке